# AsyncTask errors in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpresponse

I am working on an Android project in that i need to send the login data to an online database.
For that asynctask class is used.

but i got innerset exceptions in logcat and a force close.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    EditText un,pw;
    Button ok;
    String res;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.u_name);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwd);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GetData task = new GetData();
                task.execute();


            }
        });
    }

    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
            //String valid = "1";
            String response = null;
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/test_login/check.php", postParameters);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                res=response.toString();
               // res = res.trim();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                              
                //error.setText(res);
            return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
        result = res;
               if(result.equals("1"))
               {
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
                             "LoginSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.show();
                   Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TestActivity.class);
                   startActivity(n);
               }
                else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
                         "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

I got the following logcat errors

```
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.oranz.epark.LoginActivity$GetData.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:55)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.oranz.epark.LoginActivity$GetData.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: LoginActivity.java:55, which line is that?

Comment: seems this line "res=response.toString();", obviously the response was null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your response String being null.

You are forcing the code to be run even after try catch is executed. So if the executeHttpPost method gets into some kind of problem, ur response string will be null and in the next line you are doing,

```
 res=response.toString();
```

where repsonse is actually null and hitting the NPE.

**EDIT**

Change your try catch like this,

```
        try {
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/test_login/check.php", postParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And postExecute,

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
        result = res;
                if(result==null)
                {
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
                             "Login Failed. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.show();
                }

             else  if(result.equals("1"))
               {
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
                             "LoginSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.show();
                   Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TestActivity.class);
                   startActivity(n);
               }
                else
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, 
                         "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }

        }
```

Comment: it means you have some problem executing post method in the try. You have to check that first

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with the AsyncTask, read the log again.

```
     10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     10-11 23:43:10.819: E/AndroidRuntime(1335):     at com.oranz.epark.LoginActivity$GetData.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:55)
```

null pointer exception on line 55, it's somewhere inside doInBackground.
Turn on the debugger, go line by line and check where is null.

If I had to guess I would guess that your try/catch is throwing exception and your response is null.

Comment: i debug the program and i got the following errors in logcat       http://pastebin.com/YquMqYsU

Comment: you really have to learn to read: `Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)` connection refused. Did you declare on the manifest access to internet?

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1/test_login/check.php" so maybe your server is refusing the connection.